# Which flow to use for identity server

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, identityserver4

I have my web application.

I want to use identity server with my .net core MVC web application with vue js.

When someone accesses my website. I want to check if it is authorized or not using identity server.

That also should be checked from server side. So that if authorized then it should load my home page (or say I return my home view), otherwise it should redirect to identity server's login page.

Basically I want to protect my client views, which should not be accessible without authentication. I am using aspnet/javascriptservices with vue.

Which flow should I use?

**To more summarise:** I want to use javascriptservices SPA template (for vue.js) with identityserver and secure my views.

Comment: Can you clarify how many web applications you have? You mentioned a .Net Core MVC web application and SPA application. Would they be using the same Web API or would the SPA use the MVC web appliction too?

Comment: Mine is only one. But I also want to allow other applications (which will be any third party) to share my identity based on auth2 or openid.

Comment: SPA is with web application too.